# How to process the sdp offer with ice-candidates and generate a suitable response

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am trying to generate an sdp answer for an sdp offer. I am also using ICE, but the ice-candidates are being sent along with the sdp offer.

How to generate the appropriate sdp answer along with the response for those ice candidate pairs.

Here is the sdp offer i am receving:

```
v=0
o=root 1557075227 1557075227 IN IP4 172.24.9.236
s=***********
c=IN IP4 172.24.9.236
t=0 0
m=audio 19376 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=maxptime:150
a=ice-ufrag:37bcc460577fe3dc590be4916da2574e
a=ice-pwd:39bc5db21294c65840c4442943921476
a=candidate:Hac1809ec 1 UDP 2130706431 172.24.9.236 19376 typ host
a=candidate:S31f8f89e 1 UDP 1694498815 **.***.***.158 19376 typ srflx raddr 172.24.9.236 rport 19376
a=candidate:Hac1809ec 2 UDP 2130706430 172.24.9.236 19377 typ host
a=candidate:S31f8f89e 2 UDP 1694498814 **.***.***.158 19377 typ srflx raddr 172.24.9.236 rport 19377
a=sendrecv
```

Following is the sdpanswer generated by the webrtcendpoint.processSdpOffer():

```
v=0
o=- 3679812671 3679812671 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 101
a=inactive
a=ssrc:1635381884 cname:user1999328188@host-4a845cab
a=ice-ufrag:MdZD
a=ice-pwd:+ZxngOqy+6x1MM+0lI+CGD
a=fingerprint:sha-256 02:B7:04:92:F3:69:72:2C:15:E0:D5:FE:CE:20:63:75:B3:FD:77:DC:6E:88:FB:64:7B:B7:A6:DF:BE:A7:E7:DD
a=mid:audio0
```

The call to **gatherCandidates()** before/after processing the offer is not making any difference.
I am not able to establish media flow for an audio call. I guess the reason is that the ice negotiation is not getting completed. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: P.S: Have posted this question on google groups as well to get a speedy reply. here is the [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/JwQcbgwmMNE/PDn3qnK7BgAJ)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the `localDescription` once your answer is generated.

For example, in JavaScript, the following can be done:

```
var sdp = " ... "; // This is the SDP

remoterequest = new RTCSessionDescription({"type": "offer", "sdp": sdp});

peer.setRemoteDescription (remoterequest);

peer.createAnswer((sessionDesc) => {
   peer.setLocalDescription(sessionDesc);
}, (err) => { 
   console.log (err); 
}, {} );
```

Looks like you have an "SDP answer" but are you setting that answer as the `localDescription` once you have it being generated?